# ant task with exec returning error 7

Tags: java, ant, jenkins, exec

I am trying to build using an Ant task that uses exec. Here is a snippet of my task:

```
<exec executable="cmd" failonerror="true" osfamily="windows">
                    <arg value="/c" />
                    <arg value="${path.installer}" />
                    <arg value="-silent"/>
                    <arg value="-allowDownload"/>
                    <arg value="-eulaAccepted"/>
</exec>
```

This is essentially an installer. When I am trying to run the installer (.exe) from the path, I am getting the following error:
C:\Users\abc\jenkins\install.xml:57: exec returned: 7 (line 57 points to beginning of exec)

I ran ant with verbose option to get more details:

```
[antcall] Exiting C:\Users\abc\jenkins\install.xml.
[echo] Installing new build from C:\Users\abc\jenkins\BA\integration_win\Nuze.exe
[exec] Current OS is Windows 7
[exec] Executing 'cmd' with arguments:
[exec] '/c'
[exec] 'C:\Users\abc\jenkins\BA\integration_win\Nuze.exe
[exec] '-silent'
[exec] '-allowDownload'
[exec] '-eulaAccepted'
[exec]
[exec] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
[exec] not part of the command.
target 'install.nuze' failed with message 'exec returned: 7'.
BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\abc\jenkins\install.xml57: exec returned: 7
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:646)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:672)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:498)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccesorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExeutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:811)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

Also I can confirm that my Jenkins slave has access to C:\Users\abc\jenkins\BA\integration_win\Nuze.exe
 and I can install manually from that location without any issues. Any idea on where I am erring? I looked up error codes, but generally the tip I got is that there could be some issue with ant configuration. Any pointers? Thanks a ton in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like a ANT issue. "7" is the return code of the program you're running. You need to consult the documentation of the "nuze" program you are running.

Non-zero [error codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_code) indicate to ANT that the program has failed and programmers often return different codes to indicate to the calling program what went wrong. Standard OS stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried with the option of using <arg line..> but it still had the same issue. I have contacted my build team to see if they can find out if the issue is caused due to some problems in building the installer. I will post once I find the reason

Comment: @ShubhaP I did not expect the <arg line ..> suggestion to work. Like I said it does not appear to be an ANT issue.

Comment: Mark - I found out the issue, it was an issue with write permissions in the destination directory that I was trying to install. Once i changed the destination directory, the install succeeded. Wondering if the error can be more descriptive, but as you say, these are error codes sent out by the OS to the calling program and ANT has nothing to do with it.                                                               Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very knowledgeable on this subject but sense there are no other answers I figured I would give it a shot. From looking at similar problems maybe try re-phrasing your xml

```
<exec executable="cmd" failonerror="true" osfamily="windows">
    <arg line="/c ${path.installer} -silent -allowDownload -eulaAccepted"/>
</exec>
```